# Google sheets function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Good afternoon I have a simple issue I hope to fix in google sheets.
I am trying to create a formula in google sheets however I am not fully adept with the software.
The formula I am trying to create is the following:

Unit price (The unit price always changes) - .20 cents * Qty (gallons in fuel). In order to get the total the one thing that is causing the issue is the fact that the unit price is always changing and therefore every time we need to manually enter the number. However, that is not the hard part.

What I want to have set up is the formula for what comes after we set the unit price manually that the system automatically does the math.

Answer (score 0):

Using the little information you share (and taking a wild guess), I would say you can try the following

In cell `D2` place

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),(A2:A-$B$2)*C2:C,""))
```

To find the total of all prices use this in cell `E2`

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),(A2:A-$B$2)*C2:C,"")))
```

[image]

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)

Comment: If still in need please let us know

Comment: Thank you very much this was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=A2-B2*C2
```

[image]

or maybe:

```
=(A2-B2)*C2
```

Comment: Thank you very much this was extremely helpful.